# Angular y NodeJS obtener solo una parte del JSON que recibo de la api

Tags: json, nodejs, angular

tengo esta **API** en mi servidor en nojs :

**BACKEND**

```
router.get('/all',usuarios_controller.obtener_todos);
```

**usuarios_controller.obtener_todos**

```
exports.obtener_todos = function(req, res) {
  User.find()
    .then(usuarios => {
      if (usuarios) {
        res.json({
          status: 200,
          usuarios: usuarios
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        status: 404,
        message: "Error al obtener todos los usuarios",
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

Como se puede observar mi API devuelve un `status` y `usuarios` este ultimo es una **coleccion de usuarios** .

**FRONTEND**

Esta funcion llama a la funcion `getAll()` de  `usuarioService`

```
  cargarUsuarios() {
    console.log("ABAJO");

     this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.usuarios = data;
        console.log('DATA API = ',data)
      },
      error=>{
        console.log('Error al listar los usuarios desde el servidor')
      }
    );
  }
```

EL cual devuelve el siguiente **json**:

```
{…}
​
status: 200
​
usuarios: (3) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
__v: 0
​​​
_id: "5ca4865ec715f432d8802922"
​​​
apel_1: "xxxx"
​​​
apel_2: "xxxxx"
​​​
email: "xxxx@gmail.com"
​​​
fecha_nacimiento: "1995-04-22T22:00:00.000Z"
​​​
nombre: "xxxx angel"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
1: {…}
​​​
_id: "5ca4873849704f9cdd736893"
​​​
apel_1: "xxxx"
​​​
apel_2: "xxx"
​​​
email: "xxxx@gmail.com"
​​​
fecha_nacimiento: "1989-12-10T22:00:00.000Z"
​​​
nombre: "xxxx"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
2: {…}
​​​
_id: "5ca4873849704f9cdd736895"
​​​
apel_1: "xxxx"
​​​
apel_2: "xxxx"
​​​
email: "xxxx@gmail.com"
​​​
fecha_nacimiento: "1978-02-01T22:00:00.000Z"
​​​
nombre: "xxxxx"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
<prototype>: {…
```

Es decir, un **status** y un **array** de usuarios.
Pues bien, en esta **funcion**

```
  cargarUsuarios() {
    console.log("ABAJO");

     this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.usuarios = data;
        console.log('DATA API = ',data)
      },
      error=>{
        console.log('Error al listar los usuarios desde el servidor')
      }
    );
  }
```

me esta dando problemas al meter el **data** dentro de **usuarios**, este ultimo es de tipo   `public usuarios: Usuario[];`  como podria acceder dentro de `data` y coger solo el `array` de `Usuarios`, he intentado lo siguiente **pero no me deja** :

`this.usuarios = data.usuarios`

Comment: Sera un problema de asignación y si pruebas public usuarios = [ ] : Usuario [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Ya consegui lo que queria, lo comparto por si alguien tuvo un **problema similar** :

```
  cargarUsuarios() {
    console.log("ABAJO");

     this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
      data=>{
        //this.usuarios = data;
        if (data['status'] == 200) {
          let data_usuarios = data['usuarios'];
          this.usuarios = data_usuarios;
          console.log('DATA API = ',data)
        }
      },
      error=>{
        console.log('Error al listar los usuarios desde el servidor')
      }
    );
  }
```

con `data[nombrePropiedad]` se accede a lo que uno quiera